# How to profile surviving objects

Tags: .net, clrprofiler

i'm not too sure if CLR profiler if the right tool or not.. but what i'm trying to achieve is to be able to see the state of an object in memory such as getting disposed or not after exiting a method..

if CLR profiler is not the right tool, can someone please suggest?